# How can I convert .X files from text to binary form?

Tags: directx, file-format, linux

Is there a tool for Linux (preferably a command-line tool) that can convert from the .x text format to the binary format? I wish to use this format with Irrlicht but the text format is loading very slowly (taking around 8 seconds to load one model), so I'm wondering if the binary format will be faster.

I have seen [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/how-do-i-convert-directxs-x-from-binary-encoding-to-text-encoding-and-back), but that seems to be asking more for pointers on learning the .x format, whereas I am specifically looking for a Linux tool.

Comment: Where are you exporting it from?

Comment: I guess it's somehow easy to develop convertor yourself. since your gameengine can probably both decode and encode X file.

Comment: 8 seconds!?! That's an eternity in CPU time. Are you sure you aren't getting the time it takes to read the file from disk, make coffee, load textures, create mipmaps, and THEN parse it? I wrote a text *.x file loader and a P2@333MHz could do it in a fraction of a second.

Comment: That is to say, I don't think text vs binary is the problem. I'd check out that problem first before you invest too much effort into solving the text->binary problem. If you do want use a binary format, *.x probably is a very poor choice since it is essentially the same as *.x text but using tokens instead of single characters, e.g. comma gets a 32-bit token, semicolon gets a 32-bit token, etc.

Comment: I haven't used irrlicht in years, but I remember its .x loading gave me endless problems; if there's any other format you can use, you might be best off looking into that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply: I have been away. I am exporting from Blender. I'm importing using Irrlicht, so I'm not writing either the exporter or importer. The model I am loading was extremely high poly (around 20,000) so perhaps that was the problem. @PatrickB thanks for the info on binary -- doesn't sound helpful then (if you post that as an answer I'll tick it). In the end, I gave up on .x and I'm using the B3D format instead -- it's much simpler but suits my needs. I can load the same very-high-poly model in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no such tool -- at least not one dedicated to this task that would run on Linux (or, for that matter, Windows -- the closest you might is `meshconvert.exe` which was part of the SDK, but even if it would run via wine it probably won't do what you need it to).

The best option is probably to use a tool like Blender to do file format conversions, or write such a tool yourself. At that point it may be better to select a different file format (as you appear to have), since .X is pretty verbose and long-in-the-tooth these days (as PatrickB noted).